# How to root cause the connection issue - k8s + docker + gRpc

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, grpc

I have an issue and would like to dig more to understand the root cause:

service-A runs in one k8s pod (node.js) which uses gPRC client to connect service-B (C++, gRpc server), and it uses a service name for the connection. Both services are defined using NodePort type in k8s spec.

[Problem]

Everything works fine, **but sometimes when service-B restarts (crashes), the connection doesn't work anymore, until I restart service-A manually, it works again**. Yes, it is sometimes, othertimes, the connection still works for some other times when service-B restarts.

Obviously, this issue won't allow me to sleep because we can't guarantee that service-B does not restart/crash.

I have a few thoughts, but can't tell which is more likely the issue.

1. Is it because gRpc client doesn't re-resolve the DNS name (service name)?
2. Is it because the connection to the old pod is still not closed?
3. Did I miss any gRPC client option that handles this type of case?
4. Did I misuse the service type - instead of NodePort, I should use headless service?

Since there are many pieces, I still don't have a good picture to debug this issue properly, your input will be very appreciated.

Reference:

1. gRpc client

```
    const serviceAddr = 'nebula:9190';
    const cred = nebula.grpc.credentials.createInsecure();
    const options = {
      nebula: 'node',
      'grpc.max_receive_message_length': MESSAGE_LENGTH,
      'grpc.max_send_message_length': MESSAGE_LENGTH,
      'grpc.min_reconnect_backoff_ms': MIN_RECONNECT_BACKOFF_MS,
      'grpc.max_reconnect_backoff_ms': MAX_RECONNECT_BACKOFF_MS,
    };
    const makeClient = () => new nebula.V1Client(serviceAddr, cred, options);
```

2. K8s spec

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nebula
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: nebula-server
  ports:
    - port: 9190
      name: server
      targetPort: 9190
```